# Use Azure Storage Account for Promtheus database in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage, prometheus, azure-aks

I currently have an Azure Kubernetes cluster running with Promtheus and Grafana deployments. Prometheus is using the local cluster storage for the database and I want to mount a persistent volume in the Kubernetes cluster that points back to an Azure Storage Account (file share) for the Prometheus database.

I would like to do this because it seems cleaner than setting up a remote-write configuration and solves the issue that remote-writes solve and that is 'scalability and durability'. I've done some testing and proven out this does in fact work for a non-production, low traffic environment.

I would like to know if there are any pitfalls I should be aware of if I do move forward with this plan. Has anybody else done this and encountered any issues?

Comment: this question is somewhat opinion based, I'd argue that file shares performance is not enough for anything reasonable if prometheus is doing many small writes, I'm not sure how prometheus stores data

Answer (score 1):

Create storage class to be used for prometheus data. Update the details in Prometheus manifest file. sample is given below

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: k8s
  labels:
    prometheus: k8s
spec:
  replicas: 2
  version: PROMETHEUS_VERSION
  externalUrl: PROMETHEUS_EXTERNAL_URL
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-k8s
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - {key: k8s-app, operator: Exists}
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: alert-rules
      prometheus: k8s
  nodeSelector:
    node_label_key: node_label_value
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: PROMETHEUS_MEMORY_REQUEST
  retention: PROMETHEUS_STORAGE_RETENTION
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  storage:
    class: STORAGE_CLASS_TYPE
    selector:
    resources:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          annotation1: prometheus
      spec:
        storageClassName: STORAGE_CLASS_TYPE
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: PROMETHEUS_STORAGE_VOLUME_SIZE
```